# inputing text in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone please tell me why this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NwZ9/) doesn't work?

The idea is simple is just suppose to input the selected text into the textbox..

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="teste" maxlength="50">
<select>
    <option onClick="nelson">nelson</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function nelson(){
    document.getElementById('teste').value =+ "nelson"; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the `onclick` is not really javascript, I'd call it html (because it is a html-attribute), therefor not case sensative

Comment: Actually, there is no event be fired on selected item.
Pre-condition: click on item of select, an alert will be fired.
Step 1: choose an item in list -> show alert
Step 2: choose that item again, and there is no event fired. This is the behavior of browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **DEMO: *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/4NwZ9/23/)***

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="teste" maxlength="50" />
<select onchange="selectedItemChange(this)">
    <option value="nelson">nelson</option>
    <option value="justin">justin</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
function selectedItemChange(sel) {
    document.getElementById('teste').value = sel.value;
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
<option onClick="nelson">nelson</option>
```

- *was changed for three reasons:*

  1. `onclick` is preferred to `onClick` for consistency
  2. `nelson` needed to be changed to `nelson()` to actually call the function.
  3. Since we are dealing with a `select` html element it is better to use the
     `onchange` event on the root.

`document.getElementById('teste').value =+ "nelson";`

- *As many others have pointed out the proper operator is `+=` or `=`*

### To set initial value do the following

**DEMO: *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/4NwZ9/25/)***

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="teste" maxlength="50" />
<select id="select-people" onchange="selectedItemChange(this)">
    <option value="nelson">nelson</option>
    <option value="justin">justin</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function selectedItemChange(sel) {
    document.getElementById('teste').value = sel.value;
}

window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('teste').value = document.getElementById("select-people").value;
}
```

Comment: This would be better with some explanation. Also note that `HTMLSelectElement`s have a [`value` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59351919): http://jsbin.com/uboqew/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/uboqew/1/edit)).

Comment: added explanation I hope it helps if you need more i'd be happy to add, also updated code to use sel.value and jsFiddle to match, thanks for the advice there.

Comment: this is wrong answer just refresh and then click many times on nelson ...... how anyone accept this answer and persons upvote without checking properly ..... @abc123 brother please solve this issue by just adding first only select with null value

Comment: @anupsharma this is because the onchange event only fires when the value changes.  I'd recommend setting the initial value when window.load occurs.  I didn't include this code because I didn't think it was needed.  I believe you just want there to be another `option` with a null value? can you supply a jsfiddle and i'll update appropriately.

Comment: yes brother you are right just need to attach one another option, because our answer's always helpful for new programmers. Then we need to serve our best and error free codes with simplicity. Thanks dear

Comment: @anupsharma I updated to have a `window.onload` solution let me know if you have an easier way to solve this.  Besides adding an option like `Choose...` which is my normal method.

Answer (score 5):

There's no operator `=+`, `+=` is what You need.

Comment: Becouse You only declare this function. You have to call it. For example (with jQuery): `$(function() { nelson(); });`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the right operator is `+=` not `=+`.

The reason why this is not working is because your function has to be called :)

Just let the closure be run instantly:

```
(function nelson(){
    document.getElementById('teste').value += "nelson"; 
})();
```

or without any `function`:

```
document.getElementById('teste').value += "nelson";
```

or call it anywhere:

```
nelson();
```

Comment: on the original code I have (Didn't post it because it's 1500 code lines) I'm using the javascript in a .js page and then call it do the html.. Do I still need to call every single function?
(btw this exact same code worked fine all the week :/ )

Comment: Functions have to be called, otherwise the code inside the function is never executed. You can pull the code out of the function to let it execute instantly or just let the function execute itself like in my first example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4NwZ9/19/ - thats work even better - I had to change the drop down one left to "No wrap in < body> - can anyone tell me why pls?

Answer (score 1):

You id mistake, change `=+` to `+=`.

Try use recommender event for `select`. It is `change`.

```
<input type="text" id="teste" maxlength="50">
<select onchange="nelson(this.value);">
  <option>nelson</option>
</select>
```

And JS

```
function nelson(value){
  document.getElementById('teste').value += value; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your full working solution, it will work with your code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="teste" value="" />

    <select onchange="nelson()" id="sel_nel">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="nelson">nelson</option>
    </select>


<script>
    function nelson(){              
      document.getElementById('teste').value = document.getElementById('sel_nel').value; 
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now check brother i am sending full code and html with some changes

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle: I assume you want to change the text-input's value depending on a selection made within the `select`-tag.

--> **http://jsfiddle.net/mQyLG/2/**

**Update** (Explanation):

1. I set the value of `select` directly. If you really meant `+=`, you can change it to `input.value = select.value`.
2. I used the `onchange` event of `select` instead of a `onclick` event for every single `option`. Like this you save a lot of code ;)
3. I call the method once at start to ensure there's a initial value.
4. I changed the function's scope to match `window`. This is not the best idea and should be fit to your actual scope.