# Visit selected link on button

Tags: javascript, html

How can I visit a selected link from drop-down list on external button in a new window?

```
<select id="atheist">
    <option value="http://google.com"></option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com"></option
</select>

var select = document.getElementById("select");
select.addEventListener("change",function() { 
    var win = window.open(this.value, "_blank");
    win.focus();
},false);
```

So, i'm trying to visit/go to selected link from drop-down list on a click of a button. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QA6ex/3/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="atheist">
    <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
</select>

<input id="downloadbtn" type="button" value="download" />
```

**JS**

```
function openLink(){
    var e = document.getElementById("atheist").value;
    console.log(e);
    var win = window.open(e, "_blank");
    win.focus();
}

window.onload=function(){
    var downloadbtn = document.getElementById("downloadbtn");
    downloadbtn.onclick=openLink;
};
```

---

### [addEventListener Method jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QA6ex/4/)

**JS**

```
function openLink(){
    var e = document.getElementById("atheist").value;
    var win = window.open(e, "_blank");
    win.focus();
}

window.onload=function(){
    var downloadbtn = document.getElementById("downloadbtn");
    downloadbtn.addEventListener("click", openLink, false);
};
```

---

This is similar to the following: [inputing text in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143369/inputing-text-in-textbox/18143570#18143570)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please tell me how to visit selected link on download button, not when clicked in selection list.

Comment: You shouldn't advocate inline javascript. It's bad practice.

Comment: @RUJordan agreed, was just trying to help quickly.  My bad, changed my answer I hope it is more to your standards.

Comment: @user3477508 change added for download button

Comment: @abc123 I wont +1 because I don't like the OP (nothing personal to you) for this duplicate question -- but it's fine now. Note that `.onclick` vs `addEventListener` means only 1 event can be attached now. But it works

Comment: Although you could just do `.onclick = selectChange;` instead

Comment: @RUJordan indeed! thanks for showing me that, I normally do jQuery but like working with JavaScript since it is the code jQuery is built with.

Comment: @abc123 if you become a vanilla.js master, you'll basically never need jquery. Plus it's always good to know how your tool works, not just how to use it. :D

Comment: @abc123 We not here to like each other, but to help. Be little bit more patient with newcomers as you were one day too.
Thank you a lot for posting it.

Comment: @user3477508, have look my udpated answer.

Comment: @user3477508 updated to have two answers both doing what you want I think, let me know if I could help more.

Comment: @abc123 It's exactly what I wanted mate. Thank you once more.

Comment: @RUJordan Completed agree that you need to know how the tool works. :) Added the `addEventListener` method as well.  Completely understand not wanting to `+1` the answer since it is a duplicate.  I think the OP wants something other than what was asked with his download button click, although it is still very similar.

Comment: @RUJordan I give you attention. It is working as I wanted, nothing more needed. Selected link opens with click of a button in new tab. That's what I wanted and got it. Be more understanding Jordan.

Answer (score -1):

I am supposing here you want select the site and want to open that site after click on downlad button.

**HTML**

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="http://google.com">google</option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
</select>
<button id="myButton">Download</button>
```

**JS**

```
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    var win = window.open(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value, "_blank");
    win.focus();

},false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/37Dvs/)

Comment: This will not open a new tab/window

Comment: @RUJordan, now is it okay?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please tell me how to visit selected link on download button, not when clicked in selection list.

Comment: @user3477508, you want to visit page after click on downlaod button with selected particular site?

Comment: @SumanBogati because you failed to answer the question. This still runs a change event and not an event fired from a button.

Comment: @SumanBogati Whichever link is selected in drop-down list to visit it with click of download button.

Comment: @RUJordan this should fine is not it, please have a look updated answer.